# Ruby and telnet waiting for more data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, telnet

I am trying to login with a ruby script to login to my telnet apc.

Code:

```
server = Net::Telnet.new("Host" => "192.168.178.240", 'Timeout' => 10, "Output_log" => "output_log", "binmode" => true ,'Waittime' => 2, "telnetmode" => true )
server.cmd('apc')
server.waitfor((/:.*>|More\?/))
print a
```

I recieve the following error: I

```
irb(main):025:0> Device.reboot
Net::ReadTimeout: timed out while waiting for more data
  from app/models/device.rb:15:in `reboot'
  from (irb):25
irb(main):026:0> 

server.match(/([User+Name])\w+) { |str| puts str }
server.waitfor('password') { |str| puts str }
```

More log files, the command is stuck on the password field.

```
User Name : apc
Password  : Trying 192.168.178.240...
Connected to 192.168.178.240.

User Name : apc
Password  :
```

Comment: I think these sorts of PDU devices support SSH as well which can be a lot less messy.

Answer (score 0):

Note I have never used this library before but how does this work for you

```
login_info = {"Name" => "Your User name",
              "Password" => "Your password",
              "LoginPrompt" => /User\sName\s*:/
             }
server = Net::Telnet.new("Host" => "192.168.178.240", 'Timeout' => 10, "Output_log" => "output_log", "binmode" => true ,'Waittime' => 2)
server.login(login_info) { |c| print c } # print the output from the login attempt
server.cmd("String" => 'apc', "Match" => /:.*>|More\?/) do |a|
  print a # print the output as it is read in
end
```

This should allow you to get past the password prompt section that you are failing on right now but I don't know what other intentions you have